How to perform enhanced steps Cypress logging with grouped steps?
I followed this article and reached the state in which my Cypress logs looks like in the last image of the article.
The method presented is based on logging function names.
However, I still have 2 questions:

As much as I managed to achieve, nested functions are not displayed nested on the Cypress log, but they follow their caller. Does someone know how can I make the logSteps indenting according to their order?

For example, login() is being called by loginCM().
Cypress.Commands.add('loginCM', (username = Cypress.env("CM_USERNAME"), password = Cypress.env("CM_PASSWORD")) => {

    loginCM()

    function loginCM() {
        
        eval(Cypress.logStep)
        Logger.logBegin(`loginCM`, `username = ${username}, password = ${password}`)

        cy.clearAllLocalStorage()

        cy.intercept('POST', '*login*').as('login')
        cy.visit(getCMUrl())
        cy.login(username, password)
        cy.wait('@login').then((interception) => {
            const token = interception.response.body.token
            Cypress.env('ACCESS_CODE', token)
        })

        Logger.logEnd(`loginCM`)
    }
})

However, in log they look one after the other instead of one under the other:


As I said, this is based on functions, and so I find myself wrapping the content of each custom command in order to "logStep" their name.

For example:
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {

    login()

    function login() {

        eval(Cypress.logStep)

        cy.get('[data-test="username"]').type(username, { force: true })
        cy.get('[data-test="password"]').type(password, { force: true })
        cy.get('[type="submit"]').click({ force: true })
        elements.loader().should('not.exist')
    }
})

Is there a better way?

Blog author here. The line eval(Cypress.logStep) was intended for "step" functions inside the test; I'm not sure how it would behave if used on a custom command.
For custom commands, this is what I do (from the blog post):
Cypress.Commands.add('newUser', () => {
  const message = '**newUser** ~ registering a new user'

  Cypress.log({
    name: 'command',
    message: message,
    groupStart: true,
  })

  cy.generateEmail(false).then((email) => {
    registerEmail(email)

    cy.endGroup()
    cy.wrap(email, { log: false })
  })
})

So your example might look like this, assuming I typed everything correctly:
Cypress.Commands.add('loginCM', (username = Cypress.env("CM_USERNAME"), password = Cypress.env("CM_PASSWORD")) => {

    const message = '**newUser** ~ registering a new user'

    Cypress.log({
        name: 'command',
        message: message,
        groupStart: true,
    })

    loginCM()

    function loginCM() {
        
        cy.clearAllLocalStorage()

        cy.intercept('POST', '*login*').as('login')
        cy.visit(getCMUrl())
        cy.login(username, password)
        cy.wait('@login').then((interception) => {
            const token = interception.response.body.token
            Cypress.env('ACCESS_CODE', token)
        })
    }

    cy.endGroup()
})

I removed your Logger lines only because I don't know about them and figured they might be redundant. You're welcome to restore them.

Thank you so much for your time. Do you have any idea how can steps indentation for called steps be achieved? I would make the cypress log even clearer. For example, because loginCM calls login, it would be nice to see login step moved slightly to the right. Thx!!

With the code from the blog post, custom commands that are called from within other custom commands will be nested below them in the log too, slightly indented and hidden when you collapse the parent.
